# Magento change Ship order status

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status

In Magento order status **ship** button while clicking it automatically change **complete**. So i want to change some custom order status like **shipment**

How to change it?

Answer (score 2):

Open file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml and find node. Inside this node, add following.

```
<mystate translate="label">
    <label>My State</label>
    <statuses>
       <mystatus default="1"/>
    </statuses>
    <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
</mystate>
```

> ```
> Note : I don't recommend to edit core files. But what you can do is, set this in your own module which is depends on Mage_Sales module.
> ```

also check bellow links.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141140/magento-can-an-order-be-set-to-the-processing-state-without-creating-an-invoice

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/order-statuses

http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-order-state/

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 2):

All orders that are invoiced and shipped will be set to the **State** complete, by default this state only has the **Status** Complete. It is possible to add your own status thru System => Order Statuses, here you can add the Status Shipped (button 'Create new status').
[image: Add Status]

Next you can assign this new created status to the state complete, make sure to set it to 'Use Order Status as default'. This will use 'Shipped' when an order is both invoiced and shipped.

[image: Assign status to state]

If you want to change the order to 'Complete' after this, you can do this in the order view page, the select box shows all assigned statuses for the current state of the order.